# How would go about to display items on same line in react?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am new to using react and i have started to write a program but i have hit a wall and don't know how to overcome it.

I am trying to display movie poster with their name and release date on the side of the poster. If you see the  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAoam.png) you can see thats not the case right now, the text is being placed below the poster.

How would i go about to make the poster and text side by side?

this is my render code if the problem is within there:

```
   return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Movie logger app</h1>
      <input value={word} onChange={handleChange} />
       <button onClick={getMovieName}>Find Movie</button>
        {data.map((item) => {
           return <div key={item.id}>
             <img src={item.poster} alt=""/> <h2>{item.title}</h2> <h4>{item.date}</h4>
             </div>;
        })}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a CSS question than a React question. You can try a [flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), like so:

```
{data.map((item) => (
  <div key={item.id} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    <img src={item.poster} alt="" />
    <div style={{ marginLeft: 20, display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <h2>{item.title}</h2>
      <h4>{item.date}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap grid system to give each element the half of the screen.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```
{data.map((item) => {
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src={item.poster} alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
       <h2>{item.title}</h2> <h4>{item.date}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
})}
```

Another option could be to position your elements in a table that cover all the screen (not recommended )